# Oracle: Traversing a graph of my foreign keys?

Tags: oracle, foreign-key

Given a table, what is a query that will show foreign key constrains, both immediate and nested? I.e. if T2 has an FK on T1, and T3 has an FK on T2, I would like to show T1 -> T2 -> T3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use this statement.

```
with fk_list as (
  select parent_table.table_name parent, 
         parent_cons.constraint_name as pk_constraint,
         child_table.table_name child,
         child_cons.constraint_name as fk_constraint
  from user_tables parent_table
    join user_constraints parent_cons on parent_table.table_name = parent_cons.table_name and parent_cons.constraint_type IN ('P', 'U')
    join user_constraints child_cons on child_cons.r_constraint_name = parent_cons.constraint_name and child_cons.constraint_type   = 'R'
    join user_tables child_table on child_table.table_name = child_cons.table_name and child_table.table_name <> parent_table.table_name
)
select level, 
       fl.child,
       (select listagg(fk.column_name,',') within group (order by fk.position) from user_cons_columns fk where fk.constraint_name = fl.fk_constraint) as fk_columns,
       fl.parent,
       (select listagg(pk.column_name,',') within group (order by pk.position) from user_cons_columns pk where pk.constraint_name = fl.pk_constraint) as pk_columns
from fk_list fl
where fl.child <> fl.parent
start with fl.parent = 'root table'
connect by prior fl.child = fl.parent
order by level;
```

It is not the most efficient one, but it does work for me.

Note that it requires 11.2 due to the use of `listagg()`

Comment: Curious: does it work if there are cycles in the FK relationships?

Comment: @ypercube: I didn't test it, but I would assume the query will fail unless you use `CONNECT BY NOCYCLE`

Comment: off topic @ypercube: you should check your surreal number link on your profile page http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube

Comment: thnx @miracle173 [The Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap-consultancy-) is where I can be found usually ;)

Comment: sweet, works perfectly, many thanks!  It's the most awesome "explain plan" ever, too.